# Remove or change highlighted text in pdf file in debian

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file. Some text pieces are highlighted in yellow. I want to remove those highlights, because the color is a hell to read. Or change them to a more normal color like light grey.

Is this possible?

Comment: Attempt to the text in your PDF viewer.  Does it let you select individual words or not.  PDFs could be just a big image.  Anyway, if you can select the text, why not just copy and paste it into your favorite text editor, and read it there.

Comment: I ended up uploading it here: www.pdfescape.com. Edited and downloaded it again.